# Как передать названия спутников в конструктор, чтобы при клике по спутнику выводилось его имя?

Tags: javascript

```js
/**
 * Спутник
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {Planet} planet
 * @constructor
 */
function Satellite(data, planet) {
  this.planet = planet;
  this.x = data.x;
  this.y = data.y;

  this.move = function move() {
    /* реализация движения спутника */

    // при этом здесь доступны данные планеты
    this.planet.x;
    this.planet.y;
  }
}

/**
 * Планета
 * @param {Object} data
 * @constructor
 */
function Planet(data) {
  this.radius = data.radius;
  this.satellites = [];
  this.x = data.x;
  this.y = data.y;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.satellites.length; i++) {
    this.satellites.push(new Satellite(data.satellites[i], this));
  }

  this.move = function move() {
    /* реализация движения только планеты */

    // и запуск движения спутников
    for (var i = 0; i < this.satellites.length; i++) {
      this.satellites[i].move();
    }
  }
}

// данные о планетах
var data = [{
  name: 'Earth',
  radius: 80,
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  satellites: [{
    name: 'Moon',
    radius: 10,
    x: 20, // относительно земли
    y: 20
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Mars',
  radius: 40,
  x: 160,
  y: 180,
  satellites: [{
    name: 'Satellite name',
    radius: 1,
    x: 14, // относительно земли
    y: 18
  }]
}];

// здесь экземпляры планет
var planets = [];

// создаём планеты и сохраняем их в переменную planets
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  planets.push(new Planet(data[i]));
}
```

Comment: А что мешает? В функции для сателитов дополнительно сохранять его имя. Ведь в data вы передаете  `data.satellites[i]` . Или я что-то упустил?

Comment: @alexoander сорян, это я "упустил"(вопрос снят - протупил в другом месте..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/**
 * Спутник
 * @param {Object} data
 * @param {Planet} planet
 * @constructor
 */
function Satellite(data, planet) {
  this.planet = planet;
  this.x = data.x;
  this.y = data.y;
  this.satName = data.name;
  this.move = function move() {
    /* реализация движения спутника */

    // при этом здесь доступны данные планеты
    this.planet.x;
    this.planet.y;
  }
}

/**
 * Планета
 * @param {Object} data
 * @constructor
 */
function Planet(data) {
  this.radius = data.radius;
  this.satellites = [];
  this.name = data.name;
  this.x = data.x;
  this.y = data.y;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.satellites.length; i++) {
    this.satellites.push(new Satellite(data.satellites[i], this));
  }

  this.move = function move() {
    /* реализация движения только планеты */

    // и запуск движения спутников
    for (var i = 0; i < this.satellites.length; i++) {
      this.satellites[i].move();
    }
  }
}

// данные о планетах
var data = [{
  name: 'Earth',
  radius: 80,
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  satellites: [{
    name: 'Moon',
    radius: 10,
    x: 20, // относительно земли
    y: 20
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Mars',
  radius: 40,
  x: 160,
  y: 180,
  satellites: [{
      name: 'Satellite name Number 1',
      radius: 1,
      x: 14, // относительно земли
      y: 18
    },
    {
      name: 'Satellite Number2',
      radius: 1,
      x: 14, // относительно земли
      y: 18
    }
  ]
}];

// здесь экземпляры планет
var planets = [];

// создаём планеты и сохраняем их в переменную planets
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  planets.push(new Planet(data[i]));
}

for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++) {
  console.log("----Planet" + (i + 1) + "-------");
  var planetName = planets[i].name;
  console.log(planetName );
  console.log("Satelites of the " + planetName + ":")
  if (planets[i].satellites.length === 0) console.log("None");
  for (var j = 0; j < planets[i].satellites.length; j++) {
    console.log(planets[i].satellites[j].satName);

  }
  console.log("----End of the Info about planet" + (i+1));
}
```

Вы такое имели ввиду ?

Comment: да, огромное спасибо, извините, был заплёт с определением координат, я не на то грешил..